# Gorm one-to-one and one-to-many

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have two objects that have a one-to-one and one-to-many relationship.

```
class GroupMember {
   /**
    * InvitationCode used to join this Group
    */
   InvitationCode invitationCode

   static constraints = {
      // group creator member object won't have used an invitation code
      invitationCode(nullable: true) 
   }
}

class InvitationCode {
   /**
    * GroupMember who created the code, not used the code
    */
   GroupMember creator

   // I tried removing this, it has no effect.
   static hasMany = [members: GroupMember]
}
```

Basically, I have a `GroupMember` who owns an `InvitationCode` and can use another `InvitationCode`. Or, an `InvitationCode` can only belong-to/be-created-by one `GroupMember`, but can be used/referenced by many `GroupMember`'s

The tables look like they're set up correctly - Both tables have fields for the other: 
`INVITATION_CODE.CREATOR_ID` and `GROUP_MEMBER.INVITATION_CODE_ID`.

However, when I create a new `InvitationCode` it seems the `GroupMember` object is being updated and the `invitationCodeId` is being set to the newly created `InvitationCode`'s `id`.

```
GroupMember creator = new GroupMember(
   invitationCode: null // group creator - didn't use an invitation code
)
creator.save(flush: true)

InvitationCode invitationCode = new InvitationCode(
   creator: creator
)
invitationCode.save(flush: true)

GroupMember _creatorMember = GroupMember.findById(creator.id)
assert _creatorMember.invitationCode == invitationCode // true??
```

I never set the `creator.invitationCode` so I'm not sure how/why GORM is setting it. I'm also not sure where my mistake is in defining the domain. When I remove the `flush: true`'s I get a foreign-key restraint violation on `GroupMember.invitationCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current setup is that the `InvitationCode` domain has 2 references to the `GroupMember` domain and grails has incorrectly inferred (in your case) that:

- `invitationCode` and `creator` have a bidirectional association with each other
- `members` is a unidirectional association to the `GroupMember` class

But in reality, you want:

- `creator` to be a unidirectional association to the `GroupMember` class
- `members` to be a many-to-one relationship to the back-reference `invitationCode`, making it a bidirectional association

Understandably, grails has a problem 'guessing' how to form this complex relationship.

The key is going to be the use of the [`mappedBy`](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html) property.  I've used it successfully in mapping 2 many-to-many relationships on the same 2 classes, but not one like you need.  I *think* what you need would be to have this in your `InvitationCode` class:

```
static mappedBy = [
    members: 'invitationCode',
    creator: 'none' // because the relationship is unidirectional
]
```

Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: It looks like it's working, I didn't need to include members at all, just `creator: 'none'` did the trick. Thank you!